Why does do-release-upgrade fail with an error on Xubuntu 20.04.6 -> 22.04?
To even get this to happen, I had to remove  gnome-software, gnome-software-common, gnome-software-plugin-snap and ubuntu-software see question Investigate why packages are held back, and stop release upgrade
Then I ran do-release-upgrade under script(1).  It ended with executing triggers just before this:
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeApport.py", line 49, in apport_crash
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 495, in <module>
    def get_process_environ(proc_pid_fd: int) -> dict[str, str]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2042, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1991, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.calcDistUpgrade():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1100, in calcDistUpgrade
    if not self.cache.installTasks(self.tasks):
AttributeError: 'DistUpgradeController' object has no attribute 'tasks'
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Sat Sep  7 18:27:32 2024) ===

I can restore the backup I made yesterday, but how do I proceed?

You've not made any changes to the python3 defaults have you?

I don't remember ever doing that, but I've had this particular machine since 2016, and I'm as forgetful as any other 81-year-old.
